# RPN Calculator Ruby matching in arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm making a reverse polish notation calculator. I wrote out a gameplan and am trying to fill it in.  I'm at the part where I want to take the integers in array and move them to my new array (using shift to remove it permanently from array).

This should be easy but I just can't figure it out.  I tried identifying the integers-only with things like

```
Integer.match(x)
x.class == Integer
```

but that's not working.  I've also tried building something that will pull everything that's not in the operations array, like, this one that fails:

```
x.include?(operations)
```

I am new and not good at coding.  If you'd like to berate me about how my code is sloppy or I posted it wrong, someone already has.  I'm really trying.  Thanks,

```
class RPNCalculator
    def initialize(problem)
        @problem = problem
    end

    def resolve
        array = @problem.split(" ")
        @array = array
        operations = ["+", "-", "*"]
        @operations = operations
        queue = []
        @queue = queue

        array.map! { |x| /[0-9]/.match(x) ? x.to_i : x}

        array.each do |x|
           #THIS IS WHERE I'M BUILDING & FAILING 

            array.shift(x)
            queue << x
        end     
end
# iterate through the array
# if array elements don't match a operations element, push them into the queue
# once you have a match on the function, launch a method
# make 3 new RPN methods, one each for + - *
# method launched should affect last 2 items in the queue.
# result of that method gets pushed to the end of the queue. 
# return the remaining value in the queue as the answer

# placeholder for method +
# placeholder for method -
# placeholder for method *

end

test = "1 3 +"
mytest  = RPNCalculator.new(test)
mytest.resolve
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CJ, you want to look carefully at error messages.

```
Integer.match(x)
  #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object
```

Ruby is initially assuming that `match` is a class method of the class `Integer`.  Before sending `match` and `match`'s argument `x` to `Integer` it evaluates `x` and finds that it is neither a method or a local variable; hence the exception.  That is, you have not defined `x`.

Had you defined `x` (as a method or local variable), Ruby would have given you a different error message:

```
Integer.match(4)
  #NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for Integer:Class
```

That's because you had not defined a class method for the class `Integer`. If you had written

```
class Integer
  def self.match(x)
    2 * x
  end
end
```

Ruby would have been as happy as a clam:

```
Integer.match(4) #=> 8
```

Let's move on to your method, which Rubyists would write with two-space indents.

```
def resolve
  array = @problem.split(" ")
  @array = array
  operations = ["+", "-", "*"]
  @operations = operations
  queue = []
  @queue = queue

  array.map! { |x| /[0-9]/.match(x) ? x.to_i : x}

  array.each do |x|
     #THIS IS WHERE I'M BUILDING & FAILING 
    array.shift(x)
    queue << x
  end     
end
```

There is a problem right away in the first line:

```
array = @problem.split(" ")
  #NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

What does that error message mean?  First, let's see what IRB can tell us about the receiver of the method `split`:

```
@problem       #=> nil
@problem.class #=> NilClass
```

Now once again look at the error message.  It says that you have not defined a method `split` for the instance `nil` of the class `NilClass`. `split` is only defined for the class `String` (i.e., [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split)), so the receiver of `split` must be a string.

There are more problems with your code, but they are difficult to deal with without a foundation of what comes before. I hope my comments may have cleared up part of your problem, however.

If you are working on this problem mainly as an exercise, I think you should stand back and ask yourself what is the most effective and efficient way to learn Ruby. I think you should concentrate on problems that have been carefully designed to teach Ruby principles, starting with easy ones and then progressing to ones that are more challenging.  There are many Ruby teaching sites on the internet. Look for those and for what people say about them. Most are free but offer no mentor support. If you feel you would benefit from mentoring, I strongly recommend Ruby Learing's [Core Ruby course](http://rubylearning.org/class/).  I see a new one begins later this month. It's not free, but it's not expensive. Study notes for the course are [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

You want `x.is_a? Integer`. Ruby never creates instances of Integer directly, instead it uses the subclasses Fixnum and Bignum, which is why your `==` test fails. `is_a?` checks types all the way up the inheritance chain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generalize to floating point numbers, try adding the following method:

```
def is_decimal_number?(x)
  /\A[+-]?[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?\Z/.match(x)
end

if is_decimal_number? x
   # push x.to_f onto your stack
else
   # Check if it's a valid operator, perform the specified operation or do error handling
end
```

Note that this function is unsophisticated, it allows an optional prefix plus or minus but it doesn't cope with scientific notation, hex values, or anything else fancy.

If you just want to stick with integers, chop out the decimal and digits to the right of it:

```
def is_decimal_number?(x)
  /\A[+-]?[[:digit:]]+\Z/.match(x)
end
```

Comment: There are far more fundamental problems with CJ's code than writing a regex to see if a string is a representation of a particular type of number.  Also, how can you expect a newbie to decipher a regex--particularly with no explanation--that would confound some experienced Rubyists?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Perhaps so, but CJ specifically was asking how to separate the numbers from the operators. I gave a response in functional form, and showed how to use it with an if/else that is the essential core of an RPN calculator. Whether CJ could have created the method or not, it's usable and addresses the classification problem.